# Sonarqube Loading for ever

Tags: centos, sonarqube, sonarqube7

I have setup my sonarqube server in centos 7. I am using sonarqube 7.4. I have installed httpd and trying to access sonarqube dashboard. This will load for ever as I attached in image.

[Loading....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2A8Z.png)

I tried deleting data/es5 but no use. My sonar.properties file is as below.

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=mypassword
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
sonar.path.data=/opt/sonarqube/data
sonar.path.temp=/opt/sonarqube/temp
sonar.web.port=30056
sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
```

No errors in web.log. Please suggest me what wrong am I doing why sonarqube is not loading.

Comment: No errors in web.log is good, but is there maybe some other I formation within the logs. Not just web.log - i recommend to add the logs. - of sonar, es, and web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with network side. Below command resolved the issue.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=30056/tcp --permanent
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the same problem with sonarqube 6.7.6 LTS.

Seemed to be a browser-related problem.

I was on OSX 'El Capitan' 10.11.6.

With Safari 9.1.2, I get "Loading" indefinitely.

With Chrome 71.0.3578.98, it works.

Comment: thank you!!!!! Still need to figure out why it's failing though

Comment: Same issue with IE, Chrome Works.